# How to identify non-existing keys with reference to a table that has all mandatory keys, SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

I have the table 'Table01' which contains the keys that should be mandatory:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

And I also have the table 'Table02' which contains the records to be filtered:

| id | customer | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 |
| 2 | a | 300 |
| 3 | a | 200 |
| 4 | a | 45 |
| 1 | b | 20 |
| 2 | b | 100 |
| 3 | b | 17 |
| 1 | c | 80 |
| 4 | c | 90 |
| 2 | d | 30 |
| 3 | d | 30 |
| 4 | d | 50 |

So I want to identify which are the mandatory id's that the table 'Table02' does not have, and in turn identify which is the 'customer' of each id's that the table 'Table02' does not have.

The resulting table should look like this:

| customer | id |
| --- | --- |
| b | 4 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 1 |

What I have tried so far is a 'rigth join'.

```
proc sql;
create table table03 as
select
 b.id
from table02 a
right join table01 b
on a.id=b.id
where a.id is null;
run;
```

But that query is not identifying all the id's that should be mandatory.

I hope someone can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: I have removed all the conflicting tags. Please don't tag spam; just tag what the question is related to.

Comment: As for the question, when you edit the question to add the actual relevant tags, don't forget to add your attempt(s) as well and explain why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select cl.customerid , a.id
from
Table1 a
cross join 
( select customerid
  from table2 
  group by customerid
) cl
where not exists ( select 1 from table2 b
                   where b.customerid = cl.customerid
                   and b.id = a.id
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EXCEPT` between two sub-selects.  The first creates a matrix of all possibilities, and the *except* table is a selection of the extant customers.

Example:

```
data ids;
  do id = 1 to 4; output; end;
run;

data have;
  input id customer $ weight;
datalines;
1   a   100
2   a   300
3   a   200
4   a   45
1   b   20
2   b   100
3   b   17
1   c   80
4   c   90
2   d   30
3   d   30
4   d   50
run;

proc sql;
  create table want(label='Customers missing some ids') as
  select matrix.*
  from
    (select distinct have.customer, ids.id from have, ids) as matrix
  except
    (select customer, id from have)
  ; 
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in SQL server. Something like @eshirvana above posted, but also you can use with cte:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT t1.id, t2.Customer 
FROM Table01 t1 
cross join (select distinct customer from Table02) 
)
SELECT a.customer, a.id FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN Table02 b
ON a.id=b.id AND a.customer=b.customer
where b.id is null
```